# Displaying shortcode in footer

Tags: shortcode, footer

Using SMOF as a backend admin and trying to include a shortcode in the text field for inclusion in the footer.

I am generaing the shortcode as

```
// Add Shortcode
function copyright_shortcode() {
    // Code
    return '<?php echo date("Y") ?>';
}
add_shortcode( 'copyright', 'copyright_shortcode' );
```

and calling the data from the SMOF options panel as so

```
<?php global $data; echo do_shortcode($data['footer_text']); ?>
```

The footer is generating the text from the field however, it is putting the shortcode data in `<!-- -->.`

Comment: Can you explain this part: `return '<?php echo date("Y") ?>';`? Do you want the shortcode to output some PHP code? What's the output of `echo $data['footer_text'];`?

Comment: I want the shortcode to show the latest date. It outputs this  `<!--?php echo date("Y") ?-->`

Comment: First of all, you should change it to `return date("Y");`

Answer (score 2):

Your shortcode function is all wrong, should be:

```
function copyright_shortcode() {
    return date("Y");
}
```